# How to use MPI to organize asynchronous communication?

Tags: mpi

I plan to use MPI to build a solver that supports asynchronous communication. The basic idea is as follows.

Assume there are two parallel processes. Process 1 wants to send good solutions it finds periodically to process 2, and ask for good solutions from process 2 when it needs diversification.

1. At some point, process 1 uses `MPI_send` to send a solution to process 2. How to guarantee there is an `MPI_Rev` matching this `MPI_Send`, since this send is triggered dynamically?
2. When process 1 needs a solution, how can it send a request to process 2, and process 2 will notice its request in time?

Comment: The way to "guarantee" that every MPI_Send will have a matching MPI_Recv is to construct the code so that is what happens.  You can use MPI_Barrier to synchronize the two processes and do an exchange of solution sets at known points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the nature of the MPI_* function you call, the send will block until a matching receive has been called by another process, so you need to make sure that's going to happen in your code.
There are also non-blocking function calls MPI_Isend f.ex, which gives you a request-handle which you can check on later to see if the process' send has been received by a matching receive.

Regarding your issue, you could issue a non-blocking receive (MPI_Irecv being the most basic) and check on the status every n seconds depending on your application. The status will then be set to complete when a message has been received and is ready to be read.

If it's time sensitive, use a blocking call while waiting for a message. The blocking mechanism (in OpenMPI at least) uses a spinning poll however, so the waiting process will be eating 100% cpu.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In fact, I am more concerned on how the receiving process can detect there is a message coming? Using a while loop to check all the time? Is there better way?

Comment: np :) Yeah, using the simplest paradigm of single send to single receive, you either set up an asynchronous receive which you're responsible for checking, or use a blocking call which will return immediately when there's a new message. When blocking, OpenMPI only does busy wait (eating 100% CPU while blocking for optimal communication performance) but MPICH2 can be configured to block and wait for interrupt, going easier on CPU.

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to achieve what you want, although it is not truly asynchronous communication.

1) Use non-blocking send/recvs. Replace your send/recv calls with irecv/isend and wait. The sender can issue an isend and continue working on the next problem. At some point, you will have to issue a mpi-wait to make sure your previous send was received. Your process2 can issue a recv ahead of time using irecv and continue doing its work. Again, at some point you will call mpi-wait to make sure your irecv was received. this may be a bit cumbersome if I understand you requirement correctly.

2) A Elegant way would be to use One-Sided communication. MPI_Put, Get.

3) Restructure your algorithm in such a way that at certain intervals of time, process 1 & 2 exchange information and state.